# Custom field still shown as "not existing" even though i have retrieved all custom object metadata

Tags: salesforcedx, custom-object, custom-field, vs-code

I have retrieved all custom object metadata for Account, including the referenced custom field,
but vscode is still showing it as not existing. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the [code completion suggestions](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/apex/writing/) to work, it relies on the SObject definitions being refreshed as opposed to whether you've retrieved the new metadata.

You can do this by using the Command Palette (CTRL+Shift+P) and running the following action
`SFDX: Refresh SObject Definitions`

[image]

Comment: Awesome, that did it!

Comment: Thank you very much.